# java arraylist sum of objects

Tags: java, arraylist

If the type of my `ArrayList` is not an `Integer` (They are called Objects), how can I get the sum inside of the list? `newlist.get(i)` will return `Object` and I can't sum with "sum".

```
ArrayList newlist = new ArrayList();
newlist.add(1);
newlist.add(2);
newlist.add(3);
newlist.add(4);

for (int i = 0; i < newlist.size(); i++) {
    sum = newlist.get(i) + sum;
}
```

Comment: Why do it like that instead of `List<Integer>`?

Comment: What in Object do you even want to sum? And never ever use ArrayList without type specifier.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the runtime type and downcast the `Integer`s:

```
for(int i = 0; i < newlist.size(); i++){
    Object o = newlist.get(i);
    if (o instanceof Integer) {
        sum += ((Integer) o);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you :) If I have more reputation ,my vote will change soon

Comment: @nixiehi you can always accept an answer (the "check" sign), regardless of your rep

Comment: @nixiehi Is this answer even the thing you wanted? Is the ArrayList really mixed?? I mean of course it works like that but it's not what's best if the ArrayList is just filled with Integers...

Answer (score 0):

If the `ArrayList` is just filled with Integers then your code would be like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> newlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();
newlist.add(1);
newlist.add(2);
newlist.add(3);
newlist.add(4);

int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < newlist.size(); i++) {
    sum = newlist.get(i) + sum;
}
```